# Android url.openStream() not working

Tags: android, performance, url

I am trying to retrieve data from a website and my app keeps crashing. I have located the issue down to the openStream() command. The class I am using is defined below. I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong. Any advise is appreciated.

```
    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    //execute on background (out of the UI thread)
    protected void doInBackground() {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("URL is in here");

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                String text = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                sb.append(text);
            }
            bis.close();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

I do have permission for the Internet in my manifest file. Thanks again for any help.

Here are the errors displayed in logcat.

> 07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.annarbormap/com.example.annarbormap.MapActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:70)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at com.example.annarbormap.MapActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MapActivity.java:77)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at com.example.annarbormap.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:48)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
>   07-11 11:26:31.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     ... 11 more

Comment: Please provide the logcat or the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NetworkOnMainThreadException

You created your own doInBackground methods, but Internet connection must be only in background, put your code to overrided methods doInbackground! See example below:

In background implement getting data, in method opPostExecute - settings data to views.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
       URL url = null;
       try {
           url = new URL("URL is in here");

           BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
           byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           int bytesRead = 0;
           while((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
               String text = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
               sb.append(text);
           }
           bis.close();

       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return yourResult;
    }
}
```

or

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        doInBackground();   //your methods
        return null;
    }

    protected void doInBackground() {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("URL is in here");

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
               String text = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
               sb.append(text);
            }
           bis.close();


       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }
```

}

hope, I help you.