# Trying to download file with 45mb size in android

Tags: android, download

Hi every one I am trying to download pdf from url but it is throwing exception java.io.FileNotFoundException:url but with same code I am downloading image it is working fine I am trying to solve it for last three days but not able to do so any help much appreciated

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
    int count;
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        conection.connect();

        InputStream input = null;


        input = new BufferedInputStream(conection.getInputStream());

        File mFolder = new File("" + context.getFilesDir());
        if (!mFolder.exists())
            mFolder.mkdirs();
        File fileData = new File(mFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "myfile"+id);
        if (!fileData.exists())
            fileData.createNewFile();
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + media.id);

        input = url.openStream();
        byte[] data = new byte[(int) (media.size + 2)];
        int totalBytes=0;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1)
        {
            totalBytes+=count;
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        if(totalBytes == media.size)
        {
            Log.e("Downloaded Bytes",String.valueOf(totalBytes));
        }
        // flushing output
        output.flush();
        // closing streams
        output.close();
        input.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        isSuccess=false;
    }
    return null;
}
```

it is throwing exception from 
    input = url.openStream()

Comment: where exactly this exception is thrown (line number) ?

Comment: it was throwing from **input = url.openStream();**

Comment: And show the complete exception. With path.

Comment: Have you tried changing it to `input = connection.getInputStream();` ?

Comment: `input = url.openStream();`. Remove that line. You have already an input.

Comment: `mFolder.mkdirs();`. Check the return value so you know if it is created. Do not continue with the code if the directory is not there. You better create the directory before you try a download.

Comment: yes I have changed it  before 2 mins ago **input = new BufferedInputStream(conection.getInputStream())** this my previous code look like **input = connection.getInputStream();**

Comment: mFolder.mkdirs(); 
yes it was making file because I am downloading image with same code and it was working fine

Comment: `fileData.createNewFile();`. Remove that statement. The file output stream will create the file.

Comment: `and it was working fine`. Yes but your code will stay bad if you do not implement what i said.

Comment: If it is not workng then which line gives the exception? Post complete exception! Tell which code line throws it.

Comment: @AshishPandya Have you visited [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597157/android-url-openstream-not-working) link .

Comment: thanks greenapps I will edit code as you said :)

Comment: [greenapps](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2108972/greenapps) thank you very much commenting input = url.openStream(); working fine for me thank you very much again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
input = url.openStream();.
```

Remove that line. You have already an input